# How to do 3 divs in-line and last with auto width?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want a single line, text + text + central bar (must fill the remaining width).

I tried this:

HTML:

```
    <div class="title-cont">
    <div class="title-num">1.</div>
    <div class="title-text">Title from section</div>
    <div class="title-bar"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.title-cont { float:left; clear:left; width:600px; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; }
.title-num { float:left; font-size:20px; color:red; }
.title-text { float:left; font-size:16px; color:blue; }
.title-bar { float:left; width:100%; height:5px; background:red; }
```

URL: http://fiddle.jshell.net/5bt4S/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.title-cont { float:left; width:600px; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; }
.title-num { float:left; font-size:20px; color:red; }
.title-text { float:left; font-size:16px; color:blue; }
.title-bar {display:inline-block;width:100%; height:5px; background:red; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Stop floating the last `<div>` and hide the overflow for it and you'll get what I think you're going for:

```
.title-bar { overflow:hidden; height:5px; background:red; }
```

The bar will fill all of the available width.

[**JSFiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5bt4S/8/)

Comment: Glad to have helped (:

Answer (score 1):

**Change your css to this**

```
.title-cont { float:left: clear:left; width:600px; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; }
    .title-num { float:left; font-size:20px; color:red; }
    .title-text { float:left; font-size:16px; color:blue; }
    .title-bar { overflow:hidden; height:5px; background:red; }
```